# Finding and modifying data in rows that have been filtered in a datatables table

Tags: datatables

I have dynamically generated tables which consist of data from multiple sources. Depending on the sources, the number of columns will vary per table. I am building a feature that allows users to refresh data from various sources, updating just the relevant rows.

Once generated as HTML, the table has classes in the `tr` elements to identify where the row came from. I have written some simplified code that works in the same way as my real code to refresh the table in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dxco85v/) and shown below.

The problem is that if the user is filtering the table (with the datatables filter), the cells do not get updated if they are not visible when the user refreshes the data. In the example code, if you press the refresh button while row id 32 is visible, it will be updated. If you filter on, say, 33 and then press the button, row id 32 will not get updated with a new random value. Note that these are classes because in the real thing there are multiple classes to provide a unique id based on source and row id - multiple rows could have the same ID from different sources.

How can I update the HTML for hidden rows? As per the example code, when I get data that I need to update, I will know the row ID and I will have an array of new values in the same order as the columns (i.e. array position 0 = td:nth-child(1))

```js
$("table").dataTable();

$("#changeCell").on("click", function() {
$("tr.row-id-32 td:nth-child(1)").html("Val 32-1 NEW:"+Math.random());
$("tr.row-id-32 td:nth-child(2)").html("Val 32-2 NEW:"+Math.random());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button id="changeCell">Change row ID 32</button>

<table border=1>
<thead><tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="row-id-32"><td>Val 32-1</td><td>Val 32-2</td></tr>
  <tr class="row-id-33"><td>Val 33-1</td><td>Val 33-2</td></tr>
  <tr class="row-id-34"><td>Val 34-1</td><td>Val 34-2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataTables API to locate the row you want, regardless of whether the row is currently displayed, or is on another DataTables page.

Steps:

1. Run the snippet.
2. Click on the "Change row ID 37" button.
3. Navigate to page 2 to see the changes made to row ID 37.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "pageLength": 4
  } );

  $("#changeCell").on("click", function() {
    var node = table.rows('.row-id-37').nodes();
    $( node ).find('td:nth-child(1)').html("Val 37-1 NEW:"+Math.random());
    $( node ).find('td:nth-child(2)').html("Val 37-2 NEW:"+Math.random());
  });

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <button id="changeCell">Change row ID 37</button>

    <br><br>

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="row-id-32"><td>Val 32-1</td><td>Val 32-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="row-id-33"><td>Val 33-1</td><td>Val 33-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="row-id-34"><td>Val 34-1</td><td>Val 34-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="row-id-35"><td>Val 35-1</td><td>Val 35-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="row-id-36"><td>Val 36-1</td><td>Val 36-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="row-id-37"><td>Val 37-1</td><td>Val 37-2</td></tr>
                <tr class="row-id-38"><td>Val 38-1</td><td>Val 38-2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This builds on your logic in a couple of ways:

1. It assigns the table to a variable when you initialize it, so we can access the DataTables API:

   var table = $('#example').DataTable();

In my example, just for testing/demo, I force each page to only show 4 rows, to ensure there is a "page 2" - which is where the update happens.

2. It uses the DataTables API to select the row using a jQuery selector:

   var node = table.rows('.row-id-37').nodes();

NOTE: Because it uses a class, there may be multiple nodes returned. Given your class identifiers are unique (I assume) you may want to use an ID instead of a class in your HTML.

Once you have the node (or nodes), you can update it (or them) using jQuery - in the same way that your code does.

The benefit of using the DataTables API is that this is where *all* data is stored, regardless of which subset happens to be displayed in the DOM/page at any specific point in time.

See [`rows()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()) and [`row-selector`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) for more details.